# Creating certificate using makecert without pvk file

Tags: makecert

I am trying to create a certificate signed by the root key with `makecert`. I have no PVK file, only KEY and PEM file. I think, KEY an PEM files are also private keys. Is it right?
But if i try this:

```
.\makecert.exe -n "CN=Test Use" -iv ca.key -ic ca.cer -pe -a sha256 -len 4096 -b 01/01/2018 -e 01/01/2019 test.cer
```

I get an error:

> Error: Can't access the key of the issuer ('ca.key') Failed.

The same error with PEM file. I get no question for password. 
Is there a way to create a certificate without PVK file using `makecert`?

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution for me. I createted pvk file using `openssl`

```
openssl rsa -in ca.key -outform PVK -pvk-strong -out mykey.pvk
```

With the generated key, the comand from my initial question works.